# AAC & AVC byte stream data into ts file

Tags: h.264, http-live-streaming, rtmp, flv, aac

**Background:**
I am trying to build my own RTMP server for live streaming. (Python3+)
I have succeeded to establish an RTMP connection between the server and the client (using OBS). The client sends me the video and audio data. (audio codec: AAC, video codec: AVC).
I also built a website (HTTP), with HLS (hls.js) player (.TS & .M3U8) that works properly.

**Goal:**
What I need to do is to take the video and audio data (bytes) from the RTMP connection and join them into a .ts file container so it could be playable on my website.

**Plan:**
I planned to join them into an FLV file and then convert it to TS using FFmpeg. which actually worked with the audio data because FLV support AAC, so I generated FLV files that contained audio-only.

**Problem:**
The problem started when I tried to add the video data into the FLV file, but it is not possible because FLV does not support AVC.

**What I tried to do:**

- I can choose another file container to work with, that supports AVC/AAC but they all seem really complicated and I don't have much time for this.
- I tried to find a way to convert the AVC to H.263 and then put it inside the FLV (Because it does support H263) but I couldn't find a way.

I really need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FLV does support AVC.

Comment: Can you prove that? can you send me an FLV file with AVC video data?

Comment: "can you prove that". lol. I am not going to send you a file. You can just read the specification yourself. See page 9, CodecID 7  https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Comment: yeah I saw that, but I couldn't find any file that actually works AVC video data. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy video.flv` to make your own test file.

Comment: For times when you can't just copy the AVC codec data but instead need to encode FLV with AVC then use `ffmpeg -i some.file -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.flv` then after testing this you can later add options for audio... etc.